# consulta con ajax no me muestra los datos asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Buen día a todos

Tengo una consulta que no me muestra los datos con ajax, solo me trae la consulta cuando la realizo con el campo llave.

Esto tengo en mi controlador

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult EmbarcacionesAreaTiempo(int? id)
        {

            db.Database.Connection.Close();
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            db.Database.CommandTimeout = 60000;

            

            string query = "SELECT * FROM Reporting where ReportingPointID={0}";

            var report = db.Reportings.SqlQuery(query, id);

            db.Database.Connection.Close();
           
               
            return Json(report);
           

        }
```

y esto tengo en mi vista:

```
@model List<VTMISCCMDR.Models.Reporting>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Embarcaciones que Estuvieron en un Area por un Tiempo";
}

<h2>Embarcaciones que estuvieron en un Area por Tiempo</h2>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Introduzca los datos solicitados.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label>Numero de Area</label>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero de Area" required="" />
            </div>
           

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                <div style="float: right; display:inline-block;">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="Buscar" type="button">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<hr />

<table id="tbldatos" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" class="productth">ID</th>
            <th align="left" class="productth">VesselName</th>
            <th align="left" class="productth">ReportingPointID</th>
            <th align="left" class="productth">EntryTime</th>
            <th align="left" class="productth">ExitTime</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>


<script src="~/Content/Assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $("#buscar").click(function () {
        var id = $("#id").val();
       
         $("#tbldatos tbody tr").remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("EmbarcacionesAreaTiempo", "Reportings")',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { id:id },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    var rows = "<tr>"
                        + "<td>" + item.ReportingID + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + item.VesselName + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + item.ReportingPointID + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + item.EntryTime + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + item.ExitTime + "</td>"
                    + "</tr>";
                    $('#tbldatos tbody').append(rows);
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Cual podrá ser el problema por el cual no me trae los datos, probé con otro campo (ReportingID) y solo me devuelve la consulta cuando uso ese campo llave, pero obviamente solo me muestra 1 registro.

nota: El campo ReportingPointID debería de mostrarme varios registros que tengan el dato, y no muestra nada, que podrá ser, tengo mal el código en la parte de ajax o en el controlador?, les agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan dar. muchas gracias y saludos

Comment: Observa: estás enviando únicamente id escribes `data: { id:id },` de modo que sólo eso es enviado. Debes incluir enntre { } todo lo que deseas enviar

Comment: Gracias por contestar quevedo, es que efectivamente solo quiero enviar ese dato el "id" y que en base a ese parámetro me busque en la tabla "Reporting" todos los registros que tengan el dato del "id" que estoy enviando.